# Use switch case in python with special condition

Tags: python, linux, loops, dictionary, if-statement

i have this:

```
if you == 1:
    one.put(argument)
elif you == 3:
    pass
elif you == 4:
    two.put(argument)
elif you == 5:
    three.put(argument)
...
...
...
a lot of elif
```

I am trying to use dictionary:

```
settings = {
    1: one
    4: two,
    5: three
    ...
    ...
    ...
    other elemets of dict
    }

    if you in settings:
        settings[you].put(argument)
```

Everything is ok, but i have no idea, how to add this in dictionary:

```
elif you == 3:
    pass
```

How you think, what the better way to add `pass` statement to dictionary ?

Comment: Since you have `if you in setting:`, you can achieve the `pass` by simply omitting the `3` in the `dict` all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't need to check the existence of the item in `setting` when you're using a dictionary. The whole point of using a dictionary in this case is avoiding that check.

Secondly, If it's only 3 you can simply use an `if` condition:

```
if you == 3:
    pass
else:    
    settings[you].put(argument)
```

If there are more such items, you can use a `try-except` (without having them in your dictionary):

```
try:
    settings[you].put(argument)
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Note that since it's usually *easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*, the `try-except` method is more cleaner and Pythonic in this case, but instead of directly indexing you can also use `dict.get()` which returns `None` in case of missing the key. Then you can check if the result is `None`, then just do `pass`.